# Creating an ASP.NET MVC controller that can receive GPS coordinates and return closest shop from an Azure database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, controller, gps

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC controller that can receive GPS coordinates and return closest shop from an Azure database.

My idea is to have an app that can get the users GPS points and then the app will query an API with the GPS points and check in my database which store is closest.

My database contains stores with GPS points - as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I want to learn how to create an API that take "LAT" and "LON" as attributes and calculate which store has closest GPS points.

I have not found any good source yet how to do this.

I have already made a API that can retrieve all data from the database but want to now fix so I can get the correct shop only. see pic of my output now which is limited on one row from my database. And my code is shown in the other screenshot:

[image]

[image]